# CSS: How to arrange the complex divs?

Tags: css

I have a `div` with two inner divs.

```
<div id="x">
   <div id="icon">img</div>
   <div id="text">text</div>
</div>
```

I need to place icon in one level with first line of text to get

```
Icon "First line
      and the second."
```

The text could be separated on few lines.

Comment: Your question isn't clear and the divs aren't complex.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `vertical-align` property.

Also, points to note:

- Id's should be unique, so if you wanted to use this multiple times, you should consider using a `class` instead of `id`
- `display:inline-block` should be used to display the content next to each other.

```css
.icon{
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:url(http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
.text{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="x">
   <div class="icon"></div>
   <div class="text">text that may span <br/> two lines<br/> or even three</div>
</div>
```